# MS Access Forms Query in Combobox does not work when placed on a tabbed page

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox, tabbed

MS Access 2013 query under Combobox OnChange works on the independent form but prompts for value when I place and run it under tabbped form form page. Here are the details of what I created:

**Table:**

```
Name: TblCustomers: 
Fields: CustID, CustName, CustRegion
```

**Query:**

```
Name: QryCustomers:
SQL: SELECT *
     FROM TblCustomers
     WHERE CustRegion = Forms!FrmCustomers!cmb_Region;
```

**Form:**

```
Name: FrmCustomers:
RecordSource: QryCustomers
```

**Combobox** (on form FrmCustomers):

```
Name: cmb_Region
Items: Asia, America, Europe, MiddleEast, RoW
OnChange VBA Procedulre: 
    Private Sub cmb_Region_Change()
        Me.Requery
    End Sub
```

**Tabbed Form:**

```
Name: CustomerApp
Page1: FrmCustomers
```

I run the form **FrmCustomers** independently, it works just fine. The same form I dragged on **Page1** of tabbed form **CustomerApp** and tried to run, it prompts:

```
Enter Parameter Value:
Forms!FrmCustomers!cmb_Region
```

Please note, that I do not need the query to work independently.

How to make this form working both independently and on a tabbed form page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the issue is in `WHERE CustRegion = Forms!FrmCustomers!cmb_Region;`

originally CustRegion was found on FrmCustomers. but now that form is on another form!

you'll need something like

```
WHERE CustRegion = Forms!CustomerApp!TabControl.Form!FrmCustomers!cmb_Region;
```

i forget the exact syntax right now but something like that.

Comment: this might be better: `Forms!CustomerApp!FrmCustomers.Form!cmb_Region`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, `Forms!CustomerApp!FrmCustomers.Form!cmb_Region` works. But, if I want to run **FrmCustomers**, I need to keep **CustomerApp** open. Is there a both will work independently? I know that when the app will be finalized, we will not need to open **FrmCustomers** independently.

Comment: "Is there a both will work independently? I know that when the app will be finalized, we will not need to open FrmCustomers independently." wha?? make a copy of the form and use that. or programmatically add it to the tabbed form when you need it there.

Comment: OK, that's not giving much but I'm fine either working on the tabbed form or keeping the tabbed form open while working on the standalone form. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

remove the recordSource value for the form : FrmCustomers

add an on Open_form event to : FrmCustomers

within the open_form event have this code. (if custregion is a string add '' accordingly)

```
Dim SQL_GET as string
SQL_GET = "SELECT * FROM TblCustomers WHERE CustRegion = " & me.cmb_Region.value

me.recordsource = SQL_GET
```

this should retrieve records as per your cmp_region value. Make sure you have a default value selected.